# Is there a well known analytical solution to $e\cdot\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{a}}{a!}\cdot(-a)^{n}$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Is there a well known analytical solution to $e\cdot\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{a}}{a!}\cdot(-a)^{n}$, (with $n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$)

The first few terms of this expression (for $n=0, 1, 2, 3, ...$) are:

$1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 2, -9, 9, 50, -267, 413, 2180, -17731, etc.$

I managed to come up with an analitical solution for this, but I was wondering whether there is a well known solution for this series. I will publish my solution soon as well :)

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=-1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+-9%2C+9%2C+50%2C+-267%2C+413%2C+2180%2C+-17731&language=english&go=Search